# "Google Maps API does not support this browser" in WinForms WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps

As of last week, users have started getting a script error saying "The Google Maps API does not support this browser" when trying to map directions using the Google Maps API from within an embedded WebBrowser control in our application.  I have run into issues like this before, but was able to work around them using [IE browser emulation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6996b0c5-b44d-4040-9dbe-6206b1d9185e/webbrowser-script-error-when-using-google-maps?forum=wpf).  However, it is now erroring no matter which version of IE I have installed, which version I emulate (including IE11), or whether emulation is turned off completely. Prior to last week, this was working correctly, so I'm assuming Google changed something on their side.

Here is an example URL that gets this error:  https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=123+Main+Street,+Dobbs+Ferry,+NY&destination=123+Main+St,+White+Plains,+NY&travelmode=driving

Does anyone know of any fixes or workarounds other than replacing the terrible WinForms WebBrowser control entirely?

Comment: What does http://getright.com/useragent.html report as the user agent of that control?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're doing browser emulation correctly. As @mjwills asked what is the user agent showing as? Is it a 32bit or 64bit application? Is it a 32bit or 64bit OS?

Comment: FYI I created quick WinForms project targeting .NET 3.5 with the standard WebBrowser control. Without the emulation registry key I get the error you mentioned, with the correct key it works fine.

Comment: With the correct key my user agent shows as `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko`, without the key it shows as `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Tablet PC 2.0)`

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I forgot to mention that I am manually setting the user agent string based on the currently-installed version of IE using the urlmon.dll library.  For IE11, which I am using, it uses the string "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0;  rv:11.0) like Gecko".  The build is AnyCPU and I am running on 64 bit, but it is often run on a 32 bit OS as well by users.  I tried changing it to use your user agent string, but I am still getting the error.  I am running on .NET 4.5.1.  Since you got it working, I'm going to mess around with it some more.

Comment: I was actually able to get it to work if I built the application in 32 bit instead of AnyCPU.  But it seems when it runs in 64 bit, it still errors regardless of the user agent string I use.  I have tried using all of the following:

"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0;  rv:11.0) like Gecko"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; x64Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

Comment: FYI, the user agent string of my install of IE11 standalone is "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko".  I have tried using this in the app as well with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong after reading [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version) article.  When turning on browser emulation, I was enabling it in ...SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer... in the registry instead of ...SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer... because I was running on a 64 bit OS.  However, you are only supposed to use the WOW6432Node path if you are running a **32 bit application** on a 64 bit OS.  I changed it to use the other path for a 64 bit application on a 64 bit OS and it now works.  Thanks for the help!